# How to mirror a laptop screen to multiple laptops

Tags: windows-10, mirroring, screencasts

I'm a teacher and, for my classes, both me and my students use laptops.

I need to simultaneously mirror my laptop screen to their laptops, so that each student can see my screen in order to follow my lessons.

What's the best way for me to achieve that?

Comment: You may have more luck by asking on [softwarerecs.se] instead.

Comment: What operating system are the student's PCs running? All Windows 10? Different versions of Windows? Some use macs? Linux? Are mobile devices being used in this scenario as well? If so, Android and / or iOS?

Comment: see [Is there an open-source screen sharing tool?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/11098/3579)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use MyVision Free.

MyVision Free is a digital classroom management software offered by Netop. This software not only allows you to supervise your student’s computer screens, but also gives you the ability to take control of those screens and lock out their usage remotely.

The user interface for MyVision is clean and simple, with easy to use functionality buttons on its top bar as well as an auto-arrangement feature for screens.

MyVision Free is available for both Mac computers and PCs.

However, I found that Netop did not provide free version of this software now. If you want to use it for free, you can download the old version.
[image]

Have a nice day!